# Hibernation in java

Tags: java, database, hibernate

```
Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            if(session != null)
            {   

                String updateSql = "Update school Set name= :name Where id= :id";
                    Query query = session.createQuery(updateSql);
                    query.setParameter("name ", name );
                    query.setParameter("id", id);
                    int updateRows= query.executeUpdate();


            }
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) 
        {
            log.error("Error in updating name i ");
        }
```

here no of updated rows is 1 but update is not  committed in database. transaction is committed too.

```
Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            if(session != null)
            {   

                    School school = getSchool(id);
                    school.name (name);
                    session.update(school);


            }
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) 
        {
            log.error("Error in updating name i ");
        }
```

Instead this snippet is committed in same place.

first query is not committing data in database whereas second query is working. I want to know reason behind this

Comment: Your question is missing a question.

Comment: first query is not committing data in database whereas second query is working. I want to know reason behind this

Comment: You only execute a single query with the code provided. You are missing some code. Can you try and post something a bit more complete?

Comment: dint get u @takarii              I am using only one of these query at a time.

Comment: 2 things before you go any futher. Firstly, update your question with your actual question. Secondly, update your question with more details. You havent provided enough for us to see what is going on. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I if have correctly understood you have a problem of committing the transaction into DB.

you need to do it like this:

```
 public void UpdateSchool (School school ){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(school );
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Also I would recommend you using JPA. In this case you won't need to think about sessions at all, it will automatically Open, Close and commit session per your need.

Comment: there is another sets of code before and after this code which are committing..only this part of transaction is not committed. And the trick is query is not committed but when i m doing the same thing using object  it is committed. and i dont want to use object as it creates one extra sql statement which is a overhead